# What legal designation status does the Ukrainian flag possess, and what recent changes has it had to its status?

Tags: england-and-wales, flag

Under the town and country planning act, flags have three possible designations.

What is the designation of the Ukrainian flag, and what has been its most recent changes of status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag of Ukraine is a "Class H" advertisement under Schedule 1 of the [*The Town and Country Planning (Control of Advertisements) (England) Regulations 2007*](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2007/783), secondary to the Town and Country Planning Act.

Schedule 1 of the regulation lists under Class H

> Any country’s national flag

and it has included this since [its inception in 2007](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2007/783/made).